Calculation for divide amount between set of items (proportionally)
Facing issue while proportionally divide amount between items
 void main() {
  
  double itemA = 120.50;
  double itemB = 26.14;
  double itemC = 24.33;

 countDiscount(itemA, itemB, itemC, 20);

}


countDiscount(double itemA, double itemB, double itemC,double  percentage){
 
  double subTotal = roundDouble(itemA + itemB + itemC);
  
  print('subtotal $subTotal');
  
  double weightageA = roundDouble(itemA/subTotal);
  double weightageB = roundDouble(itemB/subTotal);
  double weightageC = roundDouble(itemC/subTotal);
                               
  print('weightage in cart item A: $weightageA');
  print('weightage in cart item B : $weightageB');
  print('weightage in cart item C : $weightageC');
  
  
  double valueToDistribute = roundDouble((percentage/100)*(subTotal));

  print('$percentage % discount of subtotal to be divided $valueToDistribute ');
  
  
  
   double itemDA=roundDouble(weightageA * valueToDistribute);  
   double itemDB=roundDouble(weightageB * valueToDistribute);
   double itemDC=roundDouble(weightageC * valueToDistribute);
  
  
 
  
   print('$percentage % discount for item A ==> $itemDA');
   print('$percentage % discount for item B ==> $itemDB');
   print('$percentage % discount for item C ==> $itemDC');
  
 
  print(roundDouble(itemDA + itemDB +itemDC)); 
}

/// 2 digits after decimal points

double roundDouble(num value){
  return (value * 100).round() / 100.0;
}

Result is not matching desire one

its supposed to be 34.19 but returns 33.85
Might be doing something wrong here. any help or hint appreciated.

You're crunching numbers with decimals, when dealing with floating-point arithmetic, rounding errors can occur, especially when performing multiple operations.
To fix this, You could round each decimal only for the presentation (showing two decimals), like this:
void countDiscount(double itemA, double itemB, double itemC, double percentage) {
  double subTotal = itemA + itemB + itemC;
  print('subtotal $subTotal');

  double weightageA = itemA / subTotal;
  double weightageB = itemB / subTotal;
  double weightageC = itemC / subTotal;

  print('weightage in cart item A: ${weightageA.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
  print('weightage in cart item B : ${weightageB.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
  print('weightage in cart item C : ${weightageC.toStringAsFixed(2)}');

  double valueToDistribute = (percentage / 100) * subTotal;
  print('$percentage % discount of subtotal to be divided ${valueToDistribute.toStringAsFixed(2)}');

  double itemDA = weightageA * valueToDistribute;
  double itemDB = weightageB * valueToDistribute;
  double itemDC = weightageC * valueToDistribute;

  print('$percentage % discount for item A ==> ${itemDA.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
  print('$percentage % discount for item B ==> ${itemDB.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
  print('$percentage % discount for item C ==> ${itemDC.toStringAsFixed(2)}');

  double totalDiscount = itemDA + itemDB + itemDC;
  print(totalDiscount.toStringAsFixed(2)); // Round total discount to 2 decimal places
}

Result:
subtotal 170.97
weightage in cart item A: 0.70
weightage in cart item B : 0.15
weightage in cart item C : 0.14
20 % discount of subtotal to be divided 34.19
20 % discount for item A ==> 24.10
20 % discount for item B ==> 5.23
20 % discount for item C ==> 4.87
34.19


Thanks for the answer still its not upto the mark can you check the total is 34.19 and if you sum discount for A B and c then its 34.20 . I need accuracy which will provide corret value though
